# Strange electrical circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits

This is a question I would like to have an explanation with: It's in [this PDF](http://www.fisme.uu.nl/nno/opgaven/bestanden/Ronde1-Theorie-2013.pdf), question 9.

[image: circuit]

> In that circuit, if switch 1 is closed, bulb A burns normally. If 2 is closed as well, do other lamps burn normally as well?

The answer is D: yes, both B and C, but why? Could somebody explain the steps in order to think? This is not homework (even though in principal it is) but I did this voluntarily on my own interest in how more advanced electrical circuits work.

Comment: It might be better if you put the circuit here (having quoted *"In that circuit"*) Regarding your homework trouble, our tag still applies to such questions ;-)

Comment: I wish I could read z german.

Comment: @Programmer looks like dutch to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you close both switches 1 and 2 and redraw the circuit, it will look like this

[image]

So bulbs A, B and C are connected in parallel. The current will flow in all the bulbs, all of them will be working

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it is part of a contest, so I'll just give you a hint.  There is nothing unusual about this circuit at all.  Just redraw it with the two switches closed and you'll see it just looks funny because of how the grounds are drawn.

Comment: uhm so if only 1 is closed, no current flows through b c because of resistence or what?